# Is the sum of $n$ terms of a harmonic progression $\frac1d\ln\left(\frac{2a+(2n-1)d}{2a-d}\right)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

Harmonic progression is $$\frac1a+\frac1{a+d}+\frac1{a+2d}+\cdots+\frac1{a+(n-1)d}$$

Its sum, as per [the BYJU'S "Harmonic Progression" page](https://byjus.com/maths/harmonic-progression/), is given to be $$\frac1d\ln\left(\frac{2a+(2n-1)d}{2a-d}\right)$$

Is this correct? I have never encountered this formula anywhere else.

Can we prove it?

I tried taking sigma of the nth term.

$$S_n=\sum T_n=(a+(n-1)d)^{-1}=e^{-ln(a+(n-1)d)}$$

Not sure how to proceed next.

Comment: No, the formula is incorrect. Just plug in a few values and see for yourself.

Comment: Have you tried $a=d=1,n=2$?

Comment: Perhaps it's an approximation. Have you tried it for long sequences?

Comment: Thankyou for your inputs. Sorry, I had not plugged values earlier. I directly started proving it. Now, after plugging values, I see that it could be an approximation. Still, if I someone could provide a derivation, that would be great.

Comment: It looks like it's the result of approximating $1/y$ by $\frac{1}{d}\int_{y-d/2}^{y+d/2} \frac{1}{x}\,dx$.

Comment: Note that this is essentially the midpoint rule for approximating the integral but in reverse.  Therefore the error analysis is exactly the error analysis done for the midpoint rule.

Comment: @BrianMoehring thanks. Putting limits in $\ln x$, I get $$\ln\frac{y+d/2}{y-d/2}$$ I thought $y$ was $a+(n-1)d$, but apparently, it's not.

Comment: You use that same approximation for each $y = a, a+d, \ldots, a+(n-1)d$ and then add them.  the upper limit for one integral will precisely equal to the lower limit for the next, so summing the integrals gives you a single integral $$\frac{1}{d}\int_{a-d/2}^{a+(n-1)d+d/2} \frac{1}{x}\,dx$$

Comment: @BrianMoehring thankyou very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first summation to be
$$S_1(n)=\frac 1{d} \left(\psi \left(\frac{a}{d}+n\right)-\psi
  \left(\frac{a}{d}\right)\right)$$ and the  expression (notice that the website cannot be accessed) is
$$S_2(n)=\frac 1{d}\log \left(\frac{2 a+d (2 n-1)}{2 a-d}\right)$$

So, let us compare
$$d \,\Delta_n=S_1(n)-S_2(n)$$ Expanding for large values of $n$
$$d \,\Delta_n=-\left(\log \left(\frac{2 d}{2 a-d}\right)+\psi
   \left(\frac{a}{d}\right)\right)+\frac{1}{24
   n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$ Using $x=\frac a d$, the constant term is
$$\log \left(\frac{2 d}{2 a-d}\right)+\psi
   \left(\frac{a}{d}\right)=\log \left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)-\psi (x)$$ but this is "small" only for large values of  $x$ since
$$\log \left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)-\psi (x)=-\frac{1}{24 x^2}\Bigg[1+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{23}{40 x^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right) \Bigg]$$

$x$ being large means that $d< a$. All of this shows where the approximation could work.

Trying for $a=1$, $d=10^{-k}$ and $n=1234$ gives the following results

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 k & S_1 & S_2 & \Delta \\
 0 & 7.695637001 & 7.811568489 & -1.1593 \times 10^{-1}\\
 1 & 48.73932701 & 48.74393465 & -4.6076 \times 10^{-3}\\
 2 & 259.5400514 & 259.5404699 & -4.1851 \times 10^{-4}\\
 3 & 804.0699535 & 804.0699869 & -3.3356 \times 10^{-7}\\
 4 & 1163.652935 & 1163.652936 & -8.6522 \times 10^{-7} \\
 5 & 1226.454377 & 1226.454377 & -1.0096 \times 10^{-8}
\end{array}
\right)$$

Trying for $a=d=1$
$$\Delta_n=H_n-\log (2 n+1)=(\gamma -\log (2))+\frac{1}{24 n^2}-\frac{1}{24
   n^3}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^4\right)$$ and $(\gamma -\log (2))=-0.116$.

So, this is not a bad approximation (at least when $ 0 \d \leq a$